# Cannot initiate active class to a particular li of the main nav

Tags: jquery

```
 <ul id="mainMenu" class="main-nav">
     <li class="nav-menu-dropdown-company active"><a class="company-         btn" href="/company">Company</a>
     <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="/try-now.php#demorequestform">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>

$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        currentPageLink = '<?=$current_url?>';
        $(".main-nav li").each(function(){
            var listLink = $(this).children('a').attr("href");
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if(currentPageLink == listLink){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

Just need to figure out how to append the class active to the the pricing page. Rest of the links stays active when clicked but pricing does no.tHave looked thru nearly every answer on Stack, but could not find answer to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're trying to add the class `active` to the URL based on the current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var path = "/"+location.pathname;
    path = "/"+'try-now.php#demorequestform'; // this shall be deleted later !
        $('a').each(function(index, element) {
         console.log($(element).attr("href"));
         console.log(path);
    if($(element).attr("href") == path)
    {
        $(element).parent().addClass("active");  
    }else{

        $(element).parent().removeClass("active");  

}



 });
  
    });
```

```html
<style>
.active {
color:red;
background:green;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainMenu" class="main-nav">
     <li class="nav-menu-dropdown-company active"><a class="company-         btn" href="/company">Company</a>
     <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="/try-now.php#demorequestform">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

i think this will be you solution as for path for test  I make it contact run time path is correct above just delete path ="/contact-us"

Update : Add Parent to element to make li the final target 
try to print in console the pathname

```
var path = "/"+location.pathname;
      consloe.log(path);
```

to understand what is the problem

still you can catch #demorequestform

```
 if(window.location.hash.substr(1); =="demorequestform" ) {
     // make li active 
    } else {
      // Fragment doesn't exist
    }
```

Comment: i think if its work you shall mark the answer as right answer, and welcome any time